# OpenShift cloud Java web application Saving and displaying working dates in UI how to solve this?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I deployed my application in Openshift RedHat cloud

Technology: Java (UI: Vaadin,service side: Spring Boot)
Server:wildfly 8.1
DB: Mysql

Example: If i save 25-07-2016 then its saving in DB like 24-07-2016 and while displaying this date its showing like 23-07-2016

any one please help me on this.

Thanks and Regards,
Harish K

Comment: need more information, is the DB date column of type date or string? different timezones?

Comment: date only @sidgate

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a timezone issue, the openshift servers are setup for the US Eastern timezone.  What timezone are you expecting to use?  You should be able to set the correct timezone in your code (and/or store the date/time with a timezone"